# Python requests_with_caching Module?

Tags: python

I am doing some coursera course for python and it wants me to get info from an API.

It says to use the "requests_with_caching" library... I found the requests-cache library and installed that however I always get the following error with the import function:

```
import requests_with_caching
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_with_caching'
```

Am I missing something here? I have no idea

I tried importing the requests-cache library, nothing works

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Are you sure `requests_with_caching` is a public package on PyPI, and not just some custom module that the course expects you to use?

Comment: I installed it via pip, windows. I downloaded the file from py.org, then executed the pip command... and no its not some module I was supposed to create. The class just said use it with no explanation..